# Save multiple csv files to PostgreSQL database using copy command through spark Scala at the same time opening multiple connections

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to use copy command to save multiple csv files in parallel to PostgreSQL database. I am able to save a single csv file to PostgreSQL using copy command. I don't want to save the csv files one by one to the PostgreSQL as it would be sequential and I would be wasting the cluster resources as it has lot of computing happening before it reach this state. I want a way by which I can open the csv files on each partition that I have and run multiple copy commands at the same time.

I was able to find one [GitHub repo](https://github.com/EDS-APHP/spark-etl/tree/master/spark-postgres) that does something similar so I tried replicating the code but I am getting the error : `Task not serializable`

The code that I am using is as below :

Import Statements :

```
import java.util.Properties
import org.postgresql.copy.{CopyManager, PGCopyInputStream, PGCopyOutputStream}
import org.postgresql.core.BaseConnection
import java.sql.{Connection, DriverManager}
import java.io._  //to get the InputStream Class
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
```

Supporting Code that might be required:

```
 //function to get the connection properties
 def getDbConnectionProperties(environment:Int) : Properties = {

    val connectionProps = new Properties()
    connectionProps.setProperty("user", user)
     connectionProps.setProperty("password", password )
    connectionProps.setProperty("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
    connectionProps
  }
val jdbcurl = "Postgres connection URL"
val connectionProps = getDbConnectionProperties(2)
val path = "dbfs:/tmp/csv" 
val extensionPattern: String = ".*.csv"
val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
val rdd = fs
      .listStatus(new Path(path))
      .filter(x => x.getPath.toString.matches("^.*/" + extensionPattern + "$"))
      .map(x => x.getPath.toString)
      .toList
      .zipWithIndex
      .map(_.swap)
      .toDS
      .rdd

val columns = """ "x", "y" ,"z" """
val table = "targettable"
val csvSqlCopy = s"""COPY "$table" ($columns) FROM STDIN WITH CSV DELIMITER '$delimiter'  NULL '' ESCAPE '"' QUOTE '"' """
val bdct_jdbcurl = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(jdbcurl);
val bdct_properties = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(properties)
```

Code that is giving error:

```
println("Starting Copy Operation per partition for the csv files" )
rdd.foreachPartition(x => {
      val conn : Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(bdct_jdbcurl.value, bdct_properties.value)
      x.foreach { s =>
        {
          println("Started converting to stream." )
          println("Value = " +s._2)
          val stream: InputStream = FileSystem
           .get(new Configuration())
           .open(new Path(s._2))
           .getWrappedStream
          println("Completed converting to stream." )
          val copyManager: CopyManager = new CopyManager(conn.asInstanceOf[BaseConnection])
          copyManager.copyIn(csvSqlCopy, stream, bulkLoadBufferSize)
        }
      }
      conn.close()
      x.toIterator
    })
println("Completed Copy Operation per partition for the csv files" )
```

This similar code seems to be running when I use the jar of the code from the GitHub. I don't know why my code is giving the task not serializable error and the other code works fine. I am trying to have my own code as library is more vast and in some of the cases it behaves differently and I won't more control over the code.

Whole Error stack Trace :

```
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:403)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:393)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2511)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:950)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:949)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:379)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:949)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:3)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:122)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:124)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:126)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:128)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:130)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:132)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:134)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:136)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:138)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:140)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:142)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:144)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:146)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:148)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw.<init>(command-462922:150)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read.<init>(command-462922:152)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$.<init>(command-462922:156)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$.<clinit>(command-462922)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<notebook>:7)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$eval$.$print(<notebook>:6)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$eval.$print(<notebook>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:793)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1054)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:645)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:644)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:644)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:576)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:572)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.execute(DriverILoop.scala:215)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:685)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:638)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$8.apply(DriverLocal.scala:373)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$8.apply(DriverLocal.scala:350)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:238)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:233)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:48)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:271)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:48)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:350)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:639)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:485)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:597)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:390)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DBFS
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DBFS, value: com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DBFS@336786be)
    - field (class: line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: fs, type: class org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem)
    - object (class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@27f0c5b3)
    - field (class: line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@7b3a478b)
    - field (class: line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@231692d6)
    - field (class: line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@2c32b978)
    - field (class: line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@43da47e5)
    - field (class: line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw, line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw@7f2c0a90)
    - field (class: line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw, line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw@57bcfaec)
    - field (class: line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw, name: $iw, type: class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw, line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw@68070927)
    - field (class: line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read, name: $iw, type: class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read$$iw)
    - object (class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read, line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read@3d606037)
    - field (class: line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88$read, type: class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd88.$read)
    - object (class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@537ebafe)
    - field (class: line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $outer, type: class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@767bea63)
    - field (class: line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $outer, type: class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@5b9cd39c)
    - field (class: line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $outer, type: class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@712e95a1)
    - field (class: line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $outer, type: class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@798416ef)
    - field (class: line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $outer, type: class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@418ceb9f)
    - field (class: line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $outer, type: class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@2cc645e)
    - field (class: line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $outer, type: class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@119f8d9)
    - field (class: line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $outer, type: class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@10ffb1aa)
    - field (class: line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $outer, type: class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@7c2bb8d)
    - field (class: line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1, name: $outer, type: class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1, <function1>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:400)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:393)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2511)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:950)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:949)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:379)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:949)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:3)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:122)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:124)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:126)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:128)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:130)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:132)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:134)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:136)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:138)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:140)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:142)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:144)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:146)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-462922:148)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$$iw.<init>(command-462922:150)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read.<init>(command-462922:152)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$.<init>(command-462922:156)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$read$.<clinit>(command-462922)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<notebook>:7)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$eval$.$print(<notebook>:6)
    at line5a6f331864c34731a7de417a6cce94bd122.$eval.$print(<notebook>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:793)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1054)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:645)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:644)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:644)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:576)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:572)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.execute(DriverILoop.scala:215)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:685)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:638)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$8.apply(DriverLocal.scala:373)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$8.apply(DriverLocal.scala:350)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:238)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:233)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:48)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:271)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:48)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:350)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:639)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:485)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:597)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:390)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong in the code?
I have tried a lot with different options but none of them is working and now I am out of ideas.

Any opinion, suggestions and different way of implementing the stuff would also be fine.

Comment: Why you dont use the DataFrameReader and DataFrameWriter ?

Comment: @maximeG dataframewriter is slow as compared to using copy command. The size of the data is huge in terms of 150 millions records and saving through dataframewriter is taking more time. Also copy is the fastest way to save data in postgres. For reading csv file from S3 I am using dataframereader only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending lot of time I was able to make it work.

The changes or the things that I had to do is as below:

1. I had to create an object that extends from Serializable.
2. I had to create a function that is performing the copy operation inside foreachpartition inside that object.
3. call that function and it was working fine.

Below is the code that I have written to make it work.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import java.io._
object copyHelper extends Serializable {
  def BulkInsertToPostgres(dataset : Dataset[(Int, String)],jdbcURLwithSchema : String, properties : Properties): Unit = {
    
    val bdct_jdbcUrlWithSchema = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(jdbcURLwithSchema);
    val bdct_properties = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(properties)
    
    println("Starting Copy Operation per partition for the csv files" )
    dataset.rdd.foreachPartition(x => {
      val conn : Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(bdct_jdbcUrlWithSchema.value, bdct_properties.value)
      x.foreach { s =>
        {
          println("Started converting to stream." )
          println("Value = " +s._2)
          val stream: InputStream = FileSystem
           .get(new Configuration())
           .open(new Path(s._2))
           .getWrappedStream
          println("Completed converting to stream." )
          val copyManager: CopyManager = new CopyManager(conn.asInstanceOf[BaseConnection])
          val rowsInserted = copyManager.copyIn(csvSqlCopy, stream, bulkLoadBufferSize)
          println("No Of rows inserted for this partition = " +rowsInserted)
        }
      }
      conn.close()
      x.toIterator
    })
println("Completed Copy Operation per partition for the csv files" )
  }
}
```